# Raptor algorithm: find next best paths

Tags: algorithms, shortest-path, routing

I'm reading [Microsoft's white paper "Round-Based Public Transit Routing" (the RAPTOR algorithm)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/raptor_alenex.pdf). What are the ways to find next best paths (path is a sequence of trips and transfers from source to destination)?
I have few ideas about it:

1. Find best path, then exclude trips (from path) from transportation network
   and rerun algorithm. (It's not clear for me how to choose new departure time).
2. Find best path **P**, then rerun algorithm with adjusted departure
       time so it's not possible to use **P**. (I think some good paths may be missed here)

What is the way to find next best paths?

Answer (score 2):

There are standard algorithms for finding the $k$ shortest paths in a graph: you provide $k$, and it returns the shortest path, second-shortest path, ..., up to the $k$th shortest path.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_shortest_path_routing.  I'd suggest that as a natural place to start.